# What does the String object reference variable actually store?

Tags: java, string, object, reference, tostring

If we look at the source code for the toString() method:

```
/** 
* This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned.
*
* @return  the string itself.
*/
public String toString() {
return this;
}
```

could someone explain what does toString() method (which is overridden in String class ) return and also where does the returned value go?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the question--it's returning a string, like every other `toString`. It overrides the default `Object.toString` so it returns the string in question instead of building the string from the name of the class and its hashcode. If it didn't override `toString` it would do the same thing--return the name of the class + hashcode.

Answer (score 2):

Note that every object in java is a reference. While Java uses references, it looks like you are dealing with objects because you don't have to care about the references when calling a method.

The `Object#toString` method needs to return a `String` reference. In case of `String` it just returns itself because that is the best String representation of a String.

`System.out::println` can work with `String`s explicitely as it is overloaded for Strings. It will just print the String content directly (or it prints `"null"` if the passed `String` is `null`).

The overloaded method that takes a general `Object` calls the `toString` method of the passed object and prints that (or it prints `"null"` if the passed object is `null`).

Comment: Could you please tell me what is actually stored in the reference variable (a)  in the above code?

Comment: The reference contains the type (`String`) and the memory location of the actual data. The actual data contains the length of the `String`, the characters and some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I may not quite understand your question but here’s a try. The system.out.println() statement is handy in java (and especially beginners) because it automatically takes in all the basic data types and prints them out in a visual output.

The reason it may not print out the hashcode or reference addresses is because of the above ease of use with println. Java doesn’t use pointers so it may be a little trickier if you’d like to find the reference addresses exactly. But if you want to do more research on references, c or c++ pointer arithmetic could help wrap your mind around it.